# Qt correct unowned QObject return semantic

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I have a QObject `SystemdDBusManager` that can return other QObjects (`Unit` class). Those objects do not have any reason to be owned by `SystemdDBusManager`, but according to [the Qt documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/ValueBasedAndPointerBasedTypes), this can imply that the returned object is owned by SystemdDBusManager.

```cpp
class SystemdDBusManager : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Unit *getUnit(QString const &name);    
};
```

What would be a good way to make it clear that the `Unit` is not owned by `SystemdDBusManager`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a shared pointer or a unique pointer to the `Unit` object, depending on how you are going to use the object.

That way, the caller will not have to care about the lifetime of the pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Write Documentation.

There is no hard rule, who owns a pointer, it's all convention. If you want the caller to take ownership, you have to make it clear in the documentation of your function.

It may also be a good idea to convey this intent in the function name, so instead of `getUnit` I'd suggest naming it `takeUnit` which implies taking ownership from SystemDBusManager.

Comment: I like to avoid documentation when I can make the code explicit. And in this case, I would prefer to stick with `getUnit` to be consistent with systemd API.

Comment: Does the system API have the same rule for ownership? Imo if one API does not transfer ownership and another does, then it's not consistent to name those functions the same. But I can see the appeal, shared pointers also work.

Comment: It is a DBus API, so all my QObjects are in fact DBus proxies that can be cloned and destroy at will without interfering with Systemd.

Comment: _I like to avoid documentation when I can make the code explicit._ I'm just working with the API (in development) of a partner company where the developers seem to have a similar thinking. Whatever they might feel self-explanatory - I've not the slightest idea... (...and am writing e-mails again and again.)